# SQL Replace first value of column with second value

Tags: sql, replace

I'm new to SQL queries, I'm trying to select the following columns:

> pm_name, party, yr_comm and yr_left.

I have data in the first 3 columns, and to create yr_left I've given yr_comm with an alias.

I've tried using a subquery in the SELECT statment to skip the first value in yr_left, but I've gotten an error saying the subquery returns more than 1 row:

```
SELECT pm_name, party, yr_comm, 
(SELECT yr_comm FROM ministry WHERE yr_comm <> "1901") AS yr_left
FROM ministry
WHERE party <> "Labor"
```

What I need to do is replace the first value in yr_left 1901 with 1903 but keep rest of the first row, and put 1904 intp the second etc, and have a null value in the bottom row of yr_left.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to do this, and what should the statement look like?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you post sample data (edit your answer for that) and desired output based on it? What RDBMS are you using (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle...)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH mtable AS (
  SELECT pm_name, party, yr_comm, rownum
  FROM ministry WHERE party <> "Labor" ORDER BY yr_comm
) SELECT m.pm_name, m.party, m.yr_comm, (
  SELECT mm.yr_comm FROM mtable mm WHERE mm.rownum = m.rownum + 1
) AS yr_left
  FROM mtable m
```

Comment: This assumes the rows in the ministry table must always be in chronological order.  We don't know for certain if that will always be a safe assumption.  But I bet you can solve that, eh?  ;-)

Comment: Good observation mate. The query results in the snapshot had it in order so it didn't strike me. But like you said it's not a good assumption to make so I've put in the `ORDER BY`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, depending on the syntax your database system allows:

```
SELECT m.pm_name, m.party, m.yr_comm,
       (SELECT min(x.yr_comm) 
          FROM ministry as x
          WHERE x.yr_comm > m.yr_comm
       ) as yr_left
  FROM ministry as m 
  ORDER by m.yr_comm
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've gotten the result I was looking for. Thanks again

Comment: @user2371802 You can also get an account here to earn points for good questions, or helping edit, etc. It all contributes to the community, and a better resource for all of us.